# Intuition of "symmetric/antisymmetric behavior in the data"?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

In [this](https://www.utc.fr/~bordesan/dokuwiki/_media/en/glorot10nipsworkshop.pdf) paper on the advantages of rectifier activations it states:

> Also recall that, in order to efficiently represent
>   symmetric/antisymmetric behavior in the data, a rectifier network
>   would need twice as many hidden units as a network of
>   symmetric/antisymmetric activation functions.

I'm assuming that data with high "symmetric/antisymmetric behavior" is data that has high standard deviations/ strong positive and negative values? If so, is the intuition behind it needing twice as many ReLU units for the same task as for example tanhs connected to ReLU being only positive? Therefore we would need two neurons with ReLU, one for the descriptions of negative values (for example with a hypothesis that makes those positive) and one for the positive values, where we would need one using tanh? If so is the size of every network using ReLU,sigmoid (which is also not symmetric) etc double the size of a tanh network given the data has strong  "symmetric/antisymmetric behavior"?